# correct interpretation of url parameters and hashtags

Tags: javascript, html, hashtag

let's say a html document has two blocks, so you can see the content from only one of them switching either with a menu button and/or url parameters using the same javascript functions as below

```
<div class="block1"> 
    <p id="tag11"> content11 </p>
    <p id="tag12"> content12 </p>
</div>
<div class="block2"> 
    <p id="tag21"> content21 </p>
    <p id="tag22"> content22 </p>
</div>
```

with url parameters (schematically):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSTART(){
        var url = new URL(window.location.href); 
        var show = url.searchParams.get("show"); 
        switch(show) { 
        case "b1":  
        showBLOCK1(); 
        break; 
        case "b2":  
        showBLOCK2(); 
        break; 
        default: 
        doSOMETHINGELSE(); 
    }
    window.onload = onSTART; 
</script>
```

Now the questions. I would like to access the specific content with url as
`http://.......htm?show=b2#tag22`

but it does not work as I wish. It seems to me that first the document is loaded, then it positioned to the provided hashtag and only then the js function is applied. As the result the content is mispositioned. Clearly I do not understand how it work.

Is it a good approach/style I use? Again, I would like to display certain block and position the content of this block using url parameters and hashtags. Is it possible?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the following line at the end of onSTART function solves the problem:

```
if(window.location.hash) {location.hash = window.location.hash.substr(0);}
```

the solution could be not very elegant, but it worked.